# Magento Order Processing error Mage::throwException('Cannot retrieve...')

Tags: magento, instance, payment, checkout

Hello wonder if anyone can help, i have a Magento setup when i click place order and the payment taking screen should launch the browser either freezes or an error is generated

```
      a:5:{i:0;s:40:"Cannot retrieve payment method instance.";i:1;s:2785:"#0                    /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Info.php(83):       Mage::throwException('Cannot retrieve...')
      #1 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Payment.php(216): Mage_Payment_Model_Info->getMethodInstance()
      #2 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Container.php(60): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Payment->getMethodInstance()
      #3 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Container.php(45): Mage_Payment_Block_Info_Container->_getInfoBlockName()
      #4 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Payment_Block_Info_Container->_prepareLayout()
      #5 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(430): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
      #6 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(446): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('checkout/onepag...', 'payment_info')
      #7 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(238): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('checkout/onepag...', 'payment_info')
      #8 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(204): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
      #9 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
      #10 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(345): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
      #11 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(270): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
      #12 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(186): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(false)
      #13 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->progressAction()
      #14 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('progress')
      #15 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
      #16 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
      #17 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
      #18 /home/tigerbaygiftsco/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
      #19 {main}";s:3:"url";s:27:"/checkout/onepage/progress/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Comment: It looks like the payment module is not loaded or incorrectly configured. What payment are you trying to use?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: paypal is the only payment module